# How to Prevent Postman from sending a 'X-Deploy-Current' Header?

Tags: postman

I am attempting to use Postman to call the REST API for an EAM tool using CURL, which I have no issue pulling what I need to using the Vendor's SDK. However, when using Postman, I was getting HTTP response when I expected JSON responses. 
The Vendor notified me that other customers had that issue using Postman, due to a X-Deploy-Current Blue/Green header being sent.

This seems to be a custom header that Postman is generating, and I cannot find any documentation online (Postman forums, SE, etc) that mention that header, or how to disable it.

The Vendor did not clue me into what the other customers had done to get that to go away, but I have dug through settings to no avail.

Comment: I am afraid that we might not have Postman experts here (or too many sysadmin experts). Just not the right audience. Sadly, half of our questions are about XPath locators (so complicated I am not surprises they do no work), or basic question how to loop over something trivial, by people who haven't learned basics yet. Maybe you may have better luck on sysadmins forum? https://serverfault.com/ or https://superuser.com/ Consider also describing what problem you want to solve, in case there is another (non-Postman) solution for it.

Comment: Are you sure that Postman adds the header? Maybe when you use Postman it chooses some proxy that adds header to your request?

Comment: I have just checked the latest Postman and send post request to a Wiremock.org mock-service. There are no any X- headers sent

Comment: I don't think so it's being sent by Postman.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is not Postman issue. You should check what proxy are you using since the header is likely added there (after the request is leaving your Postman app).

I tested Postman with [Wiremock](http://wiremock.org/) and what wiremock logs showed was:

[image]

Where I pointed out the header that I explicitly set for my request. Other ones were set by Postman defaults. As you can see there are no X- headers in place.

So I would **search for your problem resolution somewhere between Postman and the target host.**